# Change existing Theme/Template 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento-1.8, template

I Would like to Change the actual theme of My shop.
Before i ask for offers i Would like to know how much work it is - especially because all Settings, 3rd Part extensions (one stepp checkout, Gift extension and so on) all
Need to maintained.

How long a Developer Would need to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go for Marketplace theme package then you have take more hardwork to maintain existing functions.

- First, please take backup of whole site with DB, Files & Folders.
- setup new magento (as latest version or as per your choice) with new theme with earlier DB.
- Installed all your earlier extensions one by one. and manage your template (.phtml & xml) files as per new theme.
- keep in mind all earlier customization and implement it in new instance too.

If you want to designed and developed your custom theme then it will easy to manage all above things.

- Take backup of whole site with DB.
- Make clone of existing site.
- Create new package under */app/design/frontend/[packagename]/default/* and */skin/frontend/[packagename]/default/*
- now apply your theme style to whole site step by step to each modules.

Enjoy with new theme.

Comment: Hi praful rajput, many thanks for datailed Informations!!

Comment: welcome Daniel. If you face any difficulties drop your queries here..